# How to populate a table view contents from two arrays?

Tags: objective-c, c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm looking for a way to populate a table view with images and text from two separate (but parallel) arrays. I've been trying to start with two mutable arrays instantiated with all possible contents, checking against the contents of the model object, removing the "blank" entries, and copying what's left into the table view property that populates the table view cells.

(The `person` object from which `profileList` is getting its initial values is the model object being passed in.)

```
    NSMutableArray *profileList = [@[person.facebook, person.twitter, person.pinterest, person.linkedIn, person.youTube, person.googlePlus, person.flickr] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *buttonList = [@[@"btn-Facebook.png", @"btn-Twittter.png", @"btn-Pinterest.png", @"btn-LinkedIn.png", @"btn-YouTube.png", @"btn-Google+.png", @"btn-Flickr.png"] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *indicesToRemove = [@[] mutableCopy];

    //    for (NSString *index in profileList) {
    //
    //    }
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *indexContents in profileList) {
        if ([indexContents isEqual: @""]) {
        // [indicesToRemove addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
            [indicesToRemove addObject:indexContents];
        }
        i++;
    }
    for (NSString *count in indicesToRemove) {
        // [profileList removeObjectAtIndex:[count integerValue]];
        [profileList removeObject:count];
        // [buttonList removeObjectAtIndex:[count integerValue]];
    }

    self.socialMediaProfilesList = (NSArray *)profileList;
    self.socialMediaButtonsList = (NSArray *)buttonList;
```

This works for `profileList` but not for `buttonList`. (Since later, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, `cell.textLabel.text` sets fine but `cell.imageView.image` throws an exception.)

As you can perhaps tell from the commented-out lines, I tried refactoring this method to track the indexes rather than the contents, but with that I wasn't even able to get the table to load.

It seems like I'm going about this all the wrong way but I can't come up with a better approach. Any ideas?

Comment: I should add: I'm not looking for anyone to code a solution for me, just help me find how to fix (or in what new direction to start) the code myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, pointers :)

- instead of using fast-enumeration, use a plain for-loop (for (int i=0; i < COUNT; i++))
- store all indexes in a `NSMutableIndexSet`
- use `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` to clear out all objects, by calling it on both arrays

**edit**: Or, alternatively, reverse the order of the for-loop ( int=COUNT-1; i >=0; i-- ) and remove the objects from the arrays directly.

Comment: You know, I'd never known or looked into the `NSIndexSet` classes or what they're for. However, working backward through the array works perfectly, succinctly, and I never would have thought of it. Thanks for the help!